# Right-click withevents works on source .xlsm but not on .xlam addin

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, right-click

I've made a couple of macros that run through right click menu button based on the cell value. Typically, if I right click on cell with value 'XYZ', the menu button shows as 'Run macro for XYZ' and then does a bunch of operations: show a couple of user forms, run an SQL query, show and format result data.

On the original .xlsm file, on 'Thisworkbook' I have the following code:

```
Public WithEvents mxlApp  As Application

Public WithEvents mxlSh  As Worksheet

Private Sub mxlApp_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As 
Boolean)

... (do stuff here) ...

End Sub

...

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Call AutoExec

End Sub

...
```

On a separate module, I have the following function used to set my event handler

```
Public Sub AutoExec()

        Set mxlApp = Application

        Set ColectionOfMxlEventHandlers = New Collection

        ColectionOfMxlEventHandlers.Add mxlApp

        Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Name & " Initialized"

End Sub
```

The problem: on the original .xlsm file, the code works fine: every time I right-click on a cell which meets certain criteria, I get the 'Run macro for XYZ' and all is fine.

Once I save the file as .xlam and load it as addin, the code won't work.

I have been looking everywhere on the internet and here and couldn't figure out how to resolve this issue.

EDIT:

After modifying the code as kindly suggested by creamyegg, this is what I have:

In class module `clsAppEvents`:

```
Private WithEvents mxlApp As Excel.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Set mxlApp = Excel.Application

End Sub

Private Sub mxlApp_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim cBut As CommandBarButton

    On Error Resume Next

        Call CleanMenu

        If Len(Target.Value) = 8 Then

            MyId = Target.Value

            With Application

                Set cBut = .CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)

            End With

            With cBut

               .Caption = "Run SQL Query for " & MyId

               .Style = msoButtonCaption

               .FaceId = 2554

               .OnAction = "CallGenericQuery"

            End With

        End If

        With Application

                Set cBut = .CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)

        End With

        With cBut

           .Caption = "Columns_Select"

           .Style = msoButtonCaption

           .FaceId = 255

           .OnAction = "CallShowHide"

        End With

    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

in `Thisworkbook` class I have

```
Public m_objMe As clsAppEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Set m_objMe = New clsAppEvents

    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Name & " Initialized"

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    On Error Resume Next

           Call CleanMenu

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set m_objMe = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Deactivate()

    Call CleanMenu

End Sub
```

`MyId` is defined as a public string in the main module containing the `CallShowHide` and `callGenericQuery` subs

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: following up on this issue, the problem is that once I have run my macro from right-click menu once, I lose m_ObjMe, so I need to go back to VBA editor and rerun manually the `set m_ObjMe= New ClsAppEvents`

Any idea plse - a bit stuck here :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue sounds like your `WithEvents` is still in your `ThisWorkbook` Class? What you need to do is create a new class and then instantiate an instance of this on the `Workbook_Open()` event of your add-in. For example:

New Class (`clsAppEvents`):

```
Private WithEvents mxlApp As Excel.Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mxlApp = Excel.Application
End Sub

Private Sub mxlApp_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
...
End Sub
```

Add-in `ThisWorkbook` Class:

```
Private m_objMe As clsAppEvents

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set m_objMe = New clsAppEvents
End Sub

Private Sub WorkbookBeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Set m_objMe = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you creamyegg
I have tried your solution, it works fine when i run the workbook_open sub (the mxlApp is well defined then), macro runs fine
however, if i want to re-run the macro, the right click menu is not updated
typically, first time i get 'run macro for XYZ' (by right click on cell containing value 'XYZ') then macro runs fine but if right click  after that on cell containing 'ABC', i still have the same 'Run macro for XYZ' as before


Any idea plse?
thanks

Comment: @user1737597 unfortunately, without seeing more of your code, especially to do with how you are building the context menu etc., there isn't alot to go on to try and help any further.